# mssql connection using strapi

Tags: node.js, sql-server, strapi

A strapi API app connects and  works perfectly on SQLlite. however we need it to connect to SQL Express db. the msssql module is installed through npm i mssql and the connection strings have been amended in order to connect to mssql heres the config file

```
 /*    
  const fs = require( "fs" );    
  module.exports = ( { env } ) => ( {    
  defaultConnection: 'default',    
  connections: {    
    default: {    
      connector: 'bookshelf',    
      settings: {    
        client: 'sqlite',    
        filename: env( 'DATABASE_FILENAME', '.tmp/data.db' ),    
      },    
      options: {    
        useNullAsDefault: true,     
      },    
     },    
    },    
   } );    
  */    
  const sql = require('mssql')    
  module.exports = ( { env } ) => ( {    
    defaultConnection: 'default',    
    connections: {    
     default: {    
      connector: 'mssql',    
      settings: {    
        user: "***",//process.env.DB_USER,    
    password: "***",//process.env.DB_PWD,    
    database: "***",//process.env.DB_NAME,    
    server: "**.**.**.**",    
    port: 1433,    
    connectionTimeOut: 150000,    
    pool: {    
     max: 10,    
     min: 0,    
     idleTimeoutMillis: 30000    
    },    
    options: {    
      enableArithAbort: true,    
      encrypt: false,    
      trustedConnection: true       
    },    
      useNullAsDefault: true    
      }     
     }     
    }     
  })
```

the command lines commended out (for the code above) is the previous connection to sql lite that works.

now the error message is the following:
PS C:****Team\Q****_Team\AngularAPI\ui\molla-angular\strapi> npm start

> mollastrapi@0.1.0 start
> strapi start

```
[2022-07-29T08:05:53.028Z] debug ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
[2022-07-29T08:05:53.029Z] error TypeError: requireConnector(...) is not a function
at Object.load (C:\****Team\Q****_Team\AngularAPI\ui\molla- 
angular\strapi\node_modules\strapi-database\lib\connector-registry.js:20:65)
at DatabaseManager.initialize (C:\****Team\Q****_Team\AngularAPI\ui\molla- 
angular\strapi\node_modules\strapi-database\lib\database-manager.js:32:21)
at Strapi.load (C:\****Team\Q****_Team\AngularAPI\ui\molla- 
angular\strapi\node_modules\strapi\lib\Strapi.js:297:19)
at async Strapi.start (C:\****Team\Q***_Team\AngularAPI\ui\molla- 
angular\strapi\node_modules\strapi\lib\Strapi.js:156:9)
PS C:\****Team\Q****_Team\AngularAPI\ui\molla-angular\strapi>
```

Comment: Nothing seems to have changed since, [MSSQL support #5791](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/5791). Presumably the difficulty is that each SQL-ish product has a different dialect of SQL syntax - supporting multiple dialects is non-trivial.